# adding a variable to array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

im trying to build a problem that refer to how to travel from Arad to Bucharest.
you can see romania's map here:
[romania's map](http://centurion2.com/AIHomework/Searching/RomaniaMap.JPG)

my code:

```
clc;clear
goal='bucharest';
list=cell(20,5);
n=cell(20,5);

'city';
n{1,1}='arad';
n{1,2}='zerind';
n{1,3}='sibiu';
n{1,4}='timisoara';

'city';
n{2,1}='zerind';
n{2,2}='arad';
n{2,3}='oradea';

'city';
n{3,1}='sibiu';
n{3,2}='arad';
n{3,3}='oradea';
n{3,4}='fagaras';
n{3,5}='rimnicu vilcea';

'city';
n{4,1}='timisoara';
n{4,2}='arad';
n{4,3}='lugoj';

'city';
n{5,1}='oradea';
n{5,2}='zerind';
n{5,3}='sibiu';

'city';
n{6,1}='fagaras';
n{6,2}='sibiu';
n{6,3}='bucharest';

'city';
n{7,1}='rimnicu vilcea';
n{7,2}='sibiu';
n{7,3}='pitesti';
n{7,4}='craiova';

'city';
n{8,1}='lugoj';
n{8,2}='timisoara';
n{8,3}='mehadia';

'city';
n{9,1}='bucharest';
n{9,2}='fagaras';
n{9,3}='pitesti';
n{9,4}='giurgiu';
n{9,5}='urziceni';

'city';
n{10,1}='pitesti'
n{10,2}='bucharest'
n{10,3}='rimnicu vilcea'
n{10,4}='craiova'

'city'
n{11,1}='craiova';
n{11,2}='pitesti';
n{11,3}='rimnicu vilcea';

'city'
n{12,1}='mehadia';
n{12,2}='lugoj';
n{12,3}='dobreta';

'city'
n{13,1}='giurgiu';
n{13,2}='bucharest';

'city';
n{14,1}='urziceni';
n{14,2}='bucharest';
n{14,3}='hirsova';
n{14,4}='varsui';

'city';
n{15,1}='dobreta'
n{15,2}='mehadia'
n{15,3}='craiova'

'city';
n{16,1}='hirsova';
n{16,2}='urziceni';
n{16,3}='eforie';

'city';
n{17,1}='varsui';
n{17,2}='iasi';
n{17,3}='urziceni';

'city';
n{18,1}='eforie';
n{18,2}='hirsova';

'city';
n{19,1}='iasi';
n{19,2}='neamt';
n{19,3}='vaslui';

'city';
n{20,1}='neamt';
n{20,2}='iasi';


city=n{1,1};
for i=1:20
    for j=1:5
   if strcmp(n{i,j},goal)
       list{i,j}=[goal ' *GOAL*'];
       break;

   else

       list{i,j}=n{i,j};
   end
   end
end
    list{i,j}=n{i,j}
```

but it doesnt show me previous cities, i want it show me all ways from Arad to Buhcarest, like:
arad-->sibiu-->fagaras-->bucharest
arad-->timisoara-->lugoj-->mehadia-->dobreta-->craiova-->rimnicu vilcea-->sibiu-->fagaras-->bucharest
i dont want the shortest way, i want all ways fromm Arad to Bucharest

Comment: So how have you implemented that? It's quite difficult to know why you are not getting previous cities when you are not showing how you come to that result. (In short, include you code, please).

Comment: If I were you, I'd implement a Breadth-First Search (or Depth-First Search). As it stands, all you're doing is identifying the first location of the string `'bucharest'`.

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183944/romanias-cities-breadth-first-search-using-matlab). If you don't like or don't understand the responses to your question, you should clarify your question, not open new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some great network analysis methods that can be used for this sort of thing:

You can achieve this by constructing an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of the network and taking powers of the matrix to find 1 hop, 2 hop, 3 hop journeys etc...

Approximating the [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) will give you the total number of trips from any city on your map to any other city.